# Resolving dependencies.. issue for actionpack

Tags: ruby-on-rails, bundle, bundler, actionpack

When i try bundle update command retrieve this error

```
Resolving dependencies....

Bundler could not find compatible versions for gem "actionpack":
  In Gemfile:
    twitter-bootstrap-rails was resolved to 3.2.2, which depends on
      less-rails (>= 2.5.0) was resolved to 3.0.0, which depends on
        actionpack (>= 4.0)

    rails (= 4.2.5.1) was resolved to 4.2.5.1, which depends on
      actionpack (= 4.2.5.1)

    twitter-bootstrap-rails was resolved to 3.2.2, which depends on
      actionpack (>= 3.1)
```

In the first gem "actionpack" i have a compatible  version for rails but still getting the dependency error

I was looking in [rubygems.org](https://rubygems.org/) and the versions matches in almost all log report cases. Bundle interprets that '>=' matches with the gem which  depends?

**Gemfile**.

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'
ruby "2.2.4"
gem 'rails', '4.2.5.1'
gem 'sass-rails', '~> 5.0'
gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.3.0'
gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 4.1.0'
gem 'jquery-rails'
gem 'turbolinks'
gem 'jbuilder', '~> 2.0'
gem 'sdoc', '~> 0.4.0', group: :doc
gem 'puma'
gem 'puma_worker_killer'
gem 'rack-handlers'
group :development, :test do
  gem 'byebug'
end
group :development do
  gem 'web-console', '~> 2.0'
  gem 'spring'
  gem 'xray-rails'
end
group :production do
  gem 'unf'
  gem 'rails_12factor'
  gem 'sprockets', '3.7.2'
end
gem 'spree', git: 'https://github.com/spree/spree.git', branch: '3-0-stable'
gem 'spree_gateway', github: 'spree/spree_gateway', branch: '3-0-stable'
gem 'pg'
gem 'rest-client'
gem 'spree_auth_devise', github: 'spree/spree_auth_devise', branch: '3-0-stable'
git "https://#{ENV['BITBUCKET_USERNAME']}:#{ENV['BITBUCKET_PASSWORD']}@bitbucket.org/Gothmogh/spree_gems.git" do
  gem 'spree_i18n'
  gem 'spree_social'
  gem 'spree_reviews'
  gem 'spree_product_zoom'
  gem 'spree_social_products'
  gem 'spree_recently_viewed'
  gem 'spree_zaez_banner'
  gem 'spree_product_assembly'
  gem 'spree_asset_variant_options'
end
git "https://#{ENV['BITBUCKET_USERNAME']}:#{ENV['BITBUCKET_PASSWORD']}@bitbucket.org/Gothmogh/spree_custom_extensions.git" do
  gem 'spree_product_pre_posting'
end
gem 'less-rails'
gem 'therubyracer'
gem 'twitter-bootstrap-rails'
gem 'browser'
gem 'aws-sdk', '< 2.0'
gem 'spree_html_invoice', git: 'https://github.com/vinsol-spree-contrib/spree-html-invoice', branch: '3-0-stable'
```

Comment: Do you happen to have the country state select gem installed?

Comment: no, why i should have that gem to fix the dependencies issues?

Comment: Show your gem file

Comment: i've already update the ask